# Why Override is not allowed

Tags: java, javafx

I need to check username and password. if username and password is correct > open new FXML

Now How can i open new FXML If username and password is correct??

Error: Annotations is not allowed here

note: The actions code is in my other class for login button.

```
package game;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.sql.*;

public class db {

private Connection connection;
private PreparedStatement preparedStatement;

public db() throws Exception {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/riverraider";
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "146155";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
}



public void select(String username, String password) throws Exception {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1,username);
    ps.setString(2, password);

    ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();

    if (result.next()){

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
            Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/gameMenu.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }


    }else {
        System.out.println("Incorect.");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You can't declare a method inside another method. That has nothing to do with the annotation

Comment: @IlanKeshet So what is your proposal????

Comment: @Alireza Why do you need the inner function? Can you just move it out?

Comment: @IlanKeshet Yes.. open game menu :(

Comment: @Alireza You should start by explaining what exactly you are trying to do. Your code is illegal (does not compile), but without knowing your goals nobody can help you.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I need to open another fxml

Comment: I could be wrong... but actually nested functions are allowed in java... so not sure why I thought otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `db` class is not a JavaFX Application class.

This class should be separate from the rest of the JavaFX Application and called from outside. `select()` should also return a `boolean` value indicating whether it is successful.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        DB db = new DB();

        if (db.select("foo", "foopassword")) {
            Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/gameMenu.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Most likely you would already have a window open before calling your database, so that you can get username/password from the user.

All you need then is to create a new `Stage` on your own and load the FXML in the same way.